# How to read stdin without blocking using C++ future?

Tags: c++, stdin, future, nonblocking

A test program **StdoutWriter** writes some text (***{"id":0,"cmd":1}***) to stdout in 1 second and then again after 5 seconds and then waits 10 seconds and exits.  I've ran this program by itself and verified the timing and output is correct.

Another test program **StdinReader** (code given below), using a future reads stdin and prints each line.  **StdinReader** is not working as expected.

I launch the two programs from terminal with:

```
./StdoutWriter | ./StdinReader
```

The problem I'm seeing is that the reading of each line seems to be blocking until StdoutWriter exits.

The **wrong** output being observed looks like:

```
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
you wrote {"id":0,"cmd":1}
waiting...
you wrote {"id":0,"cmd":1}
waiting...
you wrote 
waiting...
you wrote 
waiting...
you wrote
```

**Correct** output should look like:

```
waiting...
waiting...
you wrote {"id":0,"cmd":1}
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
you wrote {"id":0,"cmd":1}
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
you wrote 
waiting...
you wrote 
waiting...
you wrote
```

Here's the code for StdinReader which I got from: https://gist.github.com/vmrob/ff20420a20c59b5a98a1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <string>

std::string GetLineFromCin() {
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    return line;
}

int main() {

    auto future = std::async(std::launch::async, GetLineFromCin);

    while (true) {
        if (future.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) == std::future_status::ready) {
            auto line = future.get();

            // Set a new line. Subtle race condition between the previous line
            // and this. Some lines could be missed. To aleviate, you need an
            // io-only thread. I'll give an example of that as well.
            future = std::async(std::launch::async, GetLineFromCin);

            std::cout << "you wrote " << line << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << "waiting..." << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you explicitly flushing stdout after writing?  It's likely fully-buffered when attached to a pipe (not line-buffered like when it's attached to a terminal).

Comment: @MilesBudnek That is the issue, so I will accept your comment as an answer if you want to change it.  Thanks!  StdoutWriter is a Swift program so I call fflush(__stdoutp) after print("") and it works.

Comment: Apart from the need for the writer to flush, timings (of sleeps, waits, etc) of events are variable anyway.   A ten second wait in the writer will not necessarily be exactly ten seconds.  A one second wait in the reader will not necessarily be exactly one second.

Comment: Maybe you want to use [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) ?

Comment: @Peter The timing was only a test.  I'm sending commands ad hoc from a user application and they need to be responded to quickly from a user perception perspective, so that is probably less than 1/2 second.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch See my comment to Peter.  How would poll(2) be used in this case, and would it provide any benefit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your StdoutWriter program is likely not actually writing to stdout like you think it is.  If you explicitly flush your output stream after writing then your StdinReader will likely work as you expect.

To improve performance, most I/O libraries do some level of buffering when you write to an output stream.  That means that when you write to an output stream the library will generally just keep the data internally rather than writing it directly to its underlying OS file descriptor.  This avoids paying the price of doing a syscall for every write.

The level of buffering will often vary depending on the type of file/device you're writing to:

- When writing to a terminal, output is very often line-buffered.  That means the library will flush its internal buffers and write the output to the underlying file descriptor every time you write a newline character.
- When writing to pipes or normal files output is generally fully-buffered though.  That means that the library will only flush the data from its internal buffer to the underlying file descriptor when the buffer fills or you explicitly tell it to.

Comment: Yes I assumed incorrectly that stdout to the pipe was line buffered, and the default line break in Swift's print() is a newline character.